# Not able to receive onNext and onComplete call on subscribed mono

Tags: project-reactor

I was trying reactor library and I'm not able to figure out why below mono never return back with onNext or onComplete call. I think I missing very trivial thing. Here's a sample code.

```
MyServiceService service = new MyServiceService();
    service.save("id")
            .map(myUserMono -> new MyUser(myUserMono.getName().toUpperCase(), myUserMono.getId().toUpperCase()))
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                    System.out.println("Subscribed!" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(MyUser myUser) {
                    System.out.println("OnNext on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("onError!" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted!" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                }
            });


}

private static class MyServiceService {
    private Repository myRepo = new Repository();

    public Mono<MyUser> save(String userId) {
        return myRepo.save(userId);
    }
}

private static class Repository {

    public Mono<MyUser> save(String userId) {
        return Mono.create(myUserMonoSink -> {
            Future<MyUser> submit = exe.submit(() -> this.blockingMethod(userId));
            ListenableFuture<MyUser> myUserListenableFuture = JdkFutureAdapters.listenInPoolThread(submit);
            Futures.addCallback(myUserListenableFuture, new FutureCallback<MyUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(MyUser result) {
                    myUserMonoSink.success(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    myUserMonoSink.error(t);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private MyUser blockingMethod(String userId) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return new MyUser("blocking", userId);
    }
}
```

Above code only prints Subcribed!main. What I'm not able to figure out is why that future callback is not pushing values through `myUserMonoSink.success`

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to keep in mind is that a `Flux` or `Mono` is **asynchronous**, most of the time.

Once you subscribe, the asynchronous processing of saving the user starts in the executor, but execution continues in your main code after `.subscribe(...)`.

So the `main` thread exits, terminating your test before anything was pushed to the `Mono`.

**[sidebar]: when is it ever synchronous?**

When the source of data is a Flux/Mono synchronous factory method. BUT with the added pre-requisite that the rest of the chain of operators doesn't switch execution context. That could happen either explicitly (you use a `publishOn` or `subscribeOn` operator) or implicitly (some operators like time-related ones, eg. `delayElements`, run on a separate `Scheduler`).

Simply put, your source is ran in the `ExecutorService` thread of `exe`, so the `Mono` is indeed asynchronous. Your snippet on the other hand is ran on `main`.

**How to fix the issue**

To observe the correct behavior of `Mono` in an experiment (as opposed to fully async code in production), several possibilities are available:

- keep `subscribe` with system.out.printlns, but add a `new CountDownLatch(1)` that is `.countDown()` inside `onComplete` and `onError`. `await` on the countdown latch after the `subscribe`.
- use `.log().block()` instead of `.subscribe(...)`. You lose the customization of what to do on each event, but `log()` will print those out for you (provided you have a logging framework configured). `block()` will revert to blocking mode and do pretty much what I suggested with the CountDownLatch above. It returns the value once available or throws an `Exception` in case of error.
- instead of `log()` you can customize logging or other side effects using `.doOnXXX(...)` methods (there's one for pretty much every type of event + combinations of events, eg. `doOnSubscribe`, `doOnNext`...)

If you're doing a unit test, use `StepVerifier` from the `reactor-tests` project. It will subscribe to the flux/mono and wait for events when you call `.verify()`. See the reference guide [chapter on testing](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#testing) (and the rest of the reference guide in general).

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that in created anonymous class `onSubscribe` method does nothing.
If you look at implementation of [`LambdaSubscriber`](https://github.com/reactor/reactive-streams-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/rsc/subscriber/LambdaSubscriber.java#L48), it requests some number of events.
Also it's easier to extend [`BaseSubscriber`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_ways_to_create_a_flux_mono_and_to_subscribe_to_it) as it has some predefined logic.

So your subscriber implementation would be:

```
MyServiceService service = new MyServiceService();
service.save("id")
        .map(myUserMono -> new MyUser(myUserMono.getName().toUpperCase(), myUserMono.getId().toUpperCase()))
        .subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<MyUser>() {
                @Override
                protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                    System.out.println("Subscribed!" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    request(1); // or requestUnbounded();
                }

                @Override
                protected void hookOnNext(MyUser myUser) {
                    System.out.println("OnNext on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    // request(1); // if wasn't called requestUnbounded()  2
                }

                @Override
                protected void hookOnComplete() {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted!" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                protected void hookOnError(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println("onError!" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

            });
```

Maybe it's not the best implementation, I'm new to reactor too.

Simon's answer has pretty good explanation about testing asynchronous code.